PL/SQL - Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
This is my pl/sql query. Main purpose to display data by loop iteration of row number. To able to view the data from vertical to horizontal without assign the col name one by one.
I want to use loop iteration using row numbers, because does not know the real data row on daily data execution.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    v_sqlb VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_max_rnb NUMBER;
    TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    c_cursor ref_cursor;

    -- Declare a nested table type to hold multiple column values
    TYPE value_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_result value_table;  -- Variable to hold fetched results

BEGIN
    -- Determine the maximum row number dynamically based on the data
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_max_rnb FROM (
        SELECT id FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 AS id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 AS id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 AS id FROM dual
        )
    );

    -- Initialize the dynamic SQL for column selection
    v_sqlb := 'SELECT ';

    -- Loop to dynamically generate the MAX(CASE ...) statements
    FOR i IN 1..v_max_rnb LOOP
        v_sqlb := v_sqlb || 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' || i || ' THEN value END) AS col' || i;

        -- Add a comma if it's not the last iteration
        IF i < v_max_rnb THEN
            v_sqlb := v_sqlb || ', ';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Complete the SQL query
    v_sqlb := v_sqlb || ' FROM (SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM (';

    -- Construct the inner SELECT with UNION ALL
    FOR i IN 1..v_max_rnb LOOP
        v_sqlb := v_sqlb || 'SELECT ' || i || ' AS id, ''' || CHR(64 + i) || ''' AS value FROM dual';
        IF i < v_max_rnb THEN
            v_sqlb := v_sqlb || ' UNION ALL ';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    v_sqlb := v_sqlb || '))';

    -- Output the final SQL statement for verification
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Generated SQL: ' || v_sqlb);

    -- Open the cursor for the dynamic SQL
    OPEN c_cursor FOR v_sqlb;

    -- Initialize the collection
    v_result := value_table();

    -- Fetch results into the collection
    LOOP
        DECLARE
            v_temp VARCHAR2(4000);
        BEGIN
            FETCH c_cursor INTO v_temp;
            EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;

            -- Extend the collection and store the fetched value
            v_result.EXTEND;
            v_result(v_result.COUNT) := v_temp;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c_cursor;

    -- Print the results
    FOR i IN 1..v_result.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NVL(v_result(i), 'NULL'));
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/

The script ouput that I got :
Generated SQL: SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) AS col1, MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS col2, MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN value END) AS col3, MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN value END) AS col4 FROM (SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, 'A' AS value FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, 'B' AS value FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id, 'C' AS value FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id, 'D' AS value FROM dual))
Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The desire output should be like this.
COL1    COL2    COL3   COL4
A      B       C      D


v_temp can only contain a single value. The FETCH c_cursor INTO v_temp returns 4 columns so the INTO needs 4 variables to select the results into: one per column.
